# Probability the longer segment is at least twice as long as the shorter

Tags: probability

A point is selected at random from the interval (0; 1); it then divides this interval into two segments. What is the probability that the longer segment is at least twice as long as the shorter segment?

Do we treat it as a uniform random variable and use the normalization rule to get f(x) and F(x)? I'm not really sure.

Comment: Could you give a title which indicates what the question is about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think: which points will divide the interval into two segments, one at least twice as long as the other? and, what is the probability then of choosing one of those points?

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson-I suppose the points between 0 and 1/3 and then 2/3 and 1 would split it into two with one at least double the length of the other. If this is the case the longer side would be at least 2/3 of the interval. Does this mean there is a 2/3 chance?

Comment: The points between 0 and 1/3, together with the points between 2/3 and 1, constitute two-thirds of the interval $(0,1)$; *that* means there's a 2 out of 3 chance.